# Determine the branch cuts for the following functions

Tags: complex-analysis

How would I go about determining the branch cuts for the principal logarithm function composed with the function $z^4-1$?

$\text{Log}({z^4-1})$

attempt:

The branch cuts will occur whenever $z^4-1$ is zero or negative real.

Solving $z^4-1=-x,x \geq 0$ gives

$z=(1-x)^{\frac{1}{4}}$

The only thing I know is that for $x=0$ the function yields the four fourth roots of $1$ that lie on the unit circle at$1,i,-i,-1$ I know from asking for help that the branch cuts are rays, emerging from these points.

How could I constructively find these rays and give the set for these branch cuts explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$z^4 = 1-x$$ with z complex. This has 4 solutions. These obviously depend on x, and specifically on the argument of 1-x. What are the possible arguments of 1-x? When you figure this out, consider the complex root and the 4 possible solutions given a single x.

Comment: The possible arguments would be $\pi$ and $0$, is that correct it would be $0$ if $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $\pi$ for $x>1$ correct?

Comment: That is correct. Now just consider the roots.

Comment: would it be for $0 \leq x \leq 1 (|1-x|)^{1/4}e^{ik \pi/2}$ and if $x>1 (|1-x|)^{1/4}e^{i(\pi +2k \pi)/4}$ ? k=0,1,2,3

Comment: does this mean there will be 8 rays in total, depending on the value of x, and all these rays are branch cuts? Also would there be four rays along the axes tending towards the origin and four rays along the lines $y=x$and $y=-x$ going through the origin and then growing without bound?

Comment: Or never mind, would the rays with arguments $\pi/4,3\pi/4,5\pi/4, and 7 \pi/4$ start on the edge of the unit circle and their magnitudes grow without bound?